# Java DatagramSocket sending to two different clients

Tags: java, sockets

i try to send a message over Java DatagramSocket to two different clients.

This is my send function:

```
public void sendData(String msg, UserData data) {
    byte[] bA;
    bA = msg.getBytes();

    DatagramPacket pck;
    try {
        pck = new DatagramPacket(bA, bA.length, InetAddress.getByName(data.getConnectionInfo().getString("privateAddress")), data.getConnectionInfo().getInt("privatePort"));
        ds.send(pck);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

So i call this function two times in a row with different host and port. 
But just one client gets the message. When i insert a Thread.sleep(1000) between the two calls of this function everything works fine. So why is it not possible to send two messages to two client in a row without waiting?

Thanks for your help.

Edit:
Sorry,

ds is the DatagramSocket. It is global and created at the beginning.
The addresses and ports are correct, otherwise it would also not work with the Thread.sleep inside.

DatagramSocket ds = new DatagramSocket(6312);

Comment: show us the whole code. Whats is `ds`?

Comment: Try to send two big messages without waiting. The message probably close to 8000 bytes.